# Why does my content shift when I reload the page?

Tags: css, canvas, wrapper, center

So my [site](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/lifestyle/) is locked at the top of the browser which is correct, however when I hit reload (command + R) on this gallery page it now vertically centers everything which is not what I want. It's a template based site (squarespace) with stuff I have added.

I added this css:

```
#canvas { top: 0 !important; margin-top: 0 !important;}
```

and this HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('canvas').removeAttribute('id');
document.getElementById('canvasWrapper').removeAttribute('id');}; </script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't happen to me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: safari, and also firefox is doing it, and also chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first load the page, you have a div (with ID something like "yui_3_10_1_1_1376940471763_412") that has no inline styling. So everything looks fine.

When you reload the page, that div no longer has an ID, and instead has an inline top margin added to it, apparently by Javascript, which pushes your site down.

Meanwhile, your code makes no sense. You've applied CSS to the div with id="canvas", and then used Javascript to remove that id, giving your CSS nothing to apply to.

Having removed that, your page is also throwing a JS error because a SquareSpace function in site.js is looking for the IDs you've deleted.

I'd try removing your added JS (leaving "canvas" and "canvas-wrapper" intact). Your CSS (with the "!important" tags) should override any inline styling that SquareSpace adds.

Comment: you are brilliant, thank you. The javascript was from one help site, and the css from another, when you add that with my no knowledge of coding, you get issues. Thank you.

Comment: That's what SO is for. :) Nice looking site, btw.

Comment: Thanks to SO, for my site to function the way i want. I have had a lot of help from this site. truly amazing.